# How do I make a Python request for WordPress REST API to create a custom field?

Tags: python, wordpress, rest, python-requests

For example, I have a post and I want to update it with tags and some custom field, like 'rating' or 'mood' (not using any plugin, only WP built-in options for custom fields and REST API).

`r = requests.post(WP_url, params = {'tags': tags, 'rating': rating}, auth = wp_auth)`

Something like this. It works great for updating existing post parameters and fields, but I cannot find a way to create a custom field using Python API requests only.

Comment: [WordPress's REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) has a [posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#update-a-post) endpoint you can use to create / retrieve / update tags and metadata. (Posts include WordPress pages, products, and posts. Custom fields are metadata.) The REST API is accessible from Python programs. Maybe somebody can offer some example code; I don't have any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to create a new field from request. Its depend on you WP Rest API Server, how it handles the excess argument you, if you API create a new field for any excess provided then only it will be possible to create new field.